# Drupal: Custom date widget?

Tags: drupal, datefield

I'm trying to create a custom date widget. Users can only chose a date from the next 10 days. So, instead of making them chose year, month, day, hours and minutes I want to have a single select list for the date (next 10 days) and two select lists for the time (hours and minutes).

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: customdate widget]
http://i52.tinypic.com/jikrv7.png

This is not just about changing date field settings (like granularity), I'm pretty sure I'll have to write some code to have correct dates in the select list (there could be 5 days from the current month and 5 days from the next one), and then correctly handle everything after user submits data.

What's the best way to achieve this? Where should I start from?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [hook_widget](http://drupal.org/node/344142) and possibly [hook_widget_info](http://drupal.org/node/417884) and [hook_widget_settings](http://drupal.org/node/354369). Also have a look at [CCK for developers](http://drupal.org/node/101742).